# Is there a way to create a new vector layer from a template?

Tags: qgis

I would like to be able to set up a template for a vector layer with a standard set of attributes rather the having to specify them time.  Similar to SQL "CREATE TABLE blah LIKE foo"

Is this possible?

Comment: It has just occurred to me that probably the most straight forward way of doing this is to add a layer with the right attributes, rename it and delete all the features.

Comment: Thanks to both SaultDon & fippinGeo for two good answers.   clearly I need to explore the GDAL command line tools.

Comment: Caught again by <return> posting.  And by the time I had finished editing the 5 mins were up.
 The bigger question I was wrestling with was working out better workflow for getting track data from the GPS into PostGIS in a clean form.  After reading flippinGeo answer it suddenly occurred to me that the way to do it was to load the GPX layer and then create a new feature in the Post GIS layer directly and completely eliminate the intermediate shape layer completely. Obvious, when you see it.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a template (empty dataset) created with ogr2ogr.

There is a `-where` flag that can be used on the `FID` that could look something like: `-where "FID < 0"` that should grab an empty dataset because there *probably* won't be any FID's with a value less than zero.

This isn't a "qgis" solution and requires you to use gdal on the command line - but it's an option to getting that template dataset ready to go.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what data store format you are using, but if it is SQL-based you could definitely run that command in the SQL pane against a table existing in the database.
You could use the INHERITS parameter if you wish to create cascading column modifications from the parent/template table to your newly created table

Perhaps I'm not understanding your question completely.